# How to push a view from project that based on Tab Bar Controller

Tags: objective-c

I have a project based on Tab Bar Controller. **BUT** There is one view that I has to be pushed from a button in View which belong to Tab bar controller.

This is very crazy for me that I can not push the view because that last view is not belong to Tab Bar Controller, It need to be pushed from Navigation Controller.

I have embeded Navigation controller into storyboard and Use this code :

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;
    SearchVC *prue =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Araikrab"];

    //start to push
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:prue animated:YES];
```

But it doesn´t work, Igot warning messege (Yellow icon):
Un supported Configuration
Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime asccess vis-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: To be cleared you want to push a ViewController from a TableViewController that reside into a TabViewController? Right?

Comment: Yes, 
In side the tab bar controller, there is a view that show searchBar which will show result in Tableview. Then when user press on that Tableview--->it must push a view that is not relate to tab bar controller, ANd I think I need NavigationController instead. I don´t know how to combine these 2 things.

Comment: Another question do you want the new ViewController to replace the TabBarViewController or just show it inside the TabViewController?

Comment: I wan to it just show inside the TabViewController ( if this replacement will make navigation Bar below disappeared)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to put the TableViewController inside UINavigationController so that you can push a new ViewController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:prue animated:YES];
```

That came be done either in the storyboard by adding the NavigationController into the TabViewController and put your ViewController as its root 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Or in code as the following

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myTableViewController];
myTabViewController.viewControllers =@[nav,otherTab];
```

Comment: well what i did now is

http://static.royalmassasje.com/test.html

then I put your code, but nothing work. what hapen ?

Comment: I can't open the link, it gives me 404 NotFound

Comment: ANd I still get messege :Un supported Configuration Segues initiated directly from View Controller must have an identifier


Until I remove the NavgationController.

Comment: This error means that you didn't set the identifier for that segue, be sure that the segue has an identifier on the interface builder

Comment: I found the solution. That´s because When I will link the Tab bar Controller to Navigatio COntroller I have to choose  : Relationship Segue--->view Controllers  THanks :)

Comment: I got a problem....When I rotate the device to horizontal, the Navigation Bar is disappeared. What happen ?